# Sending messages to clients on the server with cometD

Tags: java, javascript, messaging, comet, cometd

we've a lot of users on our server. We use seti for scaling which means each user is associated with a serversession. Now what we'd like to do is to implement an internal messaging just on the server.
Each user-representation has a list of contacts as an attribute which needs to be changed now and then and we thought it's a great idea if each (server) user could listen to an internal channel.

could anyone give me a hint on how to implement something like this? I am a bit confused with the words "Serversession / ClientSession / Serverchannel..."

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify basic Bayeux concepts like server, client and local sessions, messages or channels you can have a look at the [CometD 2 Java Concepts book](http://cometd.org/book/export/html/96). It's not that well polished and detailed as the [Reference Documentation](http://cometd.org/documentation) but explanation is concise.

Oort (not Seti which basically provides user presence and user node associations within Oort) uses local sessions between CometD servers to support basic clustering features.

Depending on your feature usage, your topology (any relation to persistence or business tiers behind CometD)... you could have a try to the Oort replicated objects, for example the [OortMap](http://docs.cometd.org/apidocs/org/cometd/oort/OortMap.html) object, to support user contacts replication.